# Serialize ArrayList<Objects> and back, preserving class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to send a collection of diffrent objects to server which accepts Json objects. Figuring out which is the optimal way to do this.

Plan A:
Serialize a collection of objects, like this:

```
ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
objects.put(new Human("Johhny"));
objects.put(new Cannon(13));
objects.put(new Hamburger(1.3));
String json = Utils.getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(objects);
```

Serialization works fine, and when I must deserialize, I receive array of Objects too (linked hash maps, to be precise). The problem is, I don't know which of these are Human, Cannon or Hamburger.

Is there any way to put object's class name into json, so when it's deserialized, the object mappers knows which class to use?

Plan B:
Parse each LinkedHashMap, manually determine it's true Class based on properties, and manually deserialize into object

Plan C:

- Put each type of objects into diffrent collection with specific type.
- Serialize three collections and combine them into one string with specific splitter
- Deserialize back in reversed order.

## The solution is:

Simply add mapper setting before writing to string:  `Utils.getObjectMapper().enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT).writeValueAsString(objects);`

Thanks to @dmitry-zvorygin!

Comment: use `instanceof` operator - to check which class the object belongs to and then cast it

Comment: @rohit-thomas when deserializing on a server, `instanceof` returns LinkedHashMap, which is default for unknown objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymorphic (de)serialization is all you need - 
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

Just make sure you have base class for all the entities.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, contained objects not extend any common class nor implement any common interface. Guess I'll stick with "plan B"

Comment: @JackHammer, did you read about "NON_CONCRETE_AND_ARRAYS" flag in ObjectMapper? That's actually what you need. No need to have base class at all.

Comment: After RTFM it worked like a charm! I just changed mapper option: `Utils.getObjectMapper().enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT).writeValueAsString(objects);`